# powershell invisible executable

Tags: powershell

I created a powershell script that checks if an executable is running. If it is do nothing, if it is not running, run the executable. I do this because the app cannot run as a service.

```
jcon.ps1

$Prog = "C:\Program Files (x86)\JCON\Edifact\edifact.exe"
if (! (ps | ? {$_.path -eq $prog})) {& $prog}
```

This script works when I run it through windows explorer - Right click on jcon.ps1 and click run with powershell.

However, there is an issue when I run the script via a scheduled task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2012-09-06T10:35:07.1546685</Date>
    <Author>BDPNT\jcon</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <BootTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT10M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </BootTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>BDPNT\jcon</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
   <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
       <Command>"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>-executionpolicy unrestricted -file "d:\script\jcon.ps1"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

If I run this code when "edifact.exe" is not running I see the executable is started but I cannot see the GUI. Also users report the application is not functioning properly. However the executable is running but invisible to me - no GUI. The executable is running as a process though. I can see that in the task manager.

The task is running as a local admin. Any ideas on why the GUI is not visible when I call the app through a scheduled task?

```
     <Command>"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>-executionpolicy unrestricted -file "d:\script\jcon.ps1"</Arguments>
```

I already tried the -windowstyle maximized parameter and the issue remained.

Thanks!

Comment: When the task start are you logged-in with the same local admin user as the task is executed?

Comment: Yes, BDPNT\jcon. Also the task logs indicate that they did run successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some powershell scheduled tasks which pop interactive windows.  In the Task Scheduler UI, the setting is "Run only when user is logged on".  In the XML, you need to change this setting:

```
<LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
```

to

```
<LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
```